# how to write h-bar in gnuplot?

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, graphing

We can write different greek symbols either directly from keyboard or using postscript method e.g {/Symbol a}.
I want to write reduced Planck's Constant i.e h-bar or h-cut. But I couldn't find any good way of doing it.

On a google search I found [this link](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/c/-J_px2NoNlE), but it did not satisfy. I wanted to know if there is any better of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

From version 5.4 of gnuplot you can specify characters by their unicode
value. For reduced Planck it is `\U+210F`. For example,

```
set terminal postscript portrait "Helvetica,20" size 10cm,10cm
set output 'pic.eps'
set encoding utf8
set title "Reduced Planck \U+210F"
set key off
plot "-" with lines
2 2
3 3
end
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

I quickly tried and you can copy the symbol ℏ directly to your script. Although the text editor showed an empty square it is correctly displayed in gnuplot.

**Script:** (worked with gnuplot 4.6.0).

```
set title "ℏ" font ",24"
plot sin(x)
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]